# Spaces in Bash dialog

Tags: bash, unix, dialog

I am trying to get a bash dialog to output a list of data with --checklist.

I have this defining what is on the list:

```
menuitems="$menuitems $n $item$disksize off\n"
```

But if I put a space between $item and $disksize like so:

```
menuitems="$menuitems $n $item $disksize off\n"
```

Nothing will happen. I have tried putting in some other forms of whitespace and unicode/ASCII codes with no luck, do you have any recommendations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you can't distinguish between spaces that belong to an item and spaces that separate items in the list. The solution is to use an array:

```
menuitems+=( "$n" "$item$disksize" "off" )

dialog ... --checklist "foo" $height $width $listHeight "${menuitems[@]}"
```

Quoting the expansion of the array produces a list of words, each of which is quoted to protect spaces contained in individual elements of the array.

Comment: List-height is missing before menu items.

Comment: This seems to work perfectly; Thank you VERY much.

I was aware of the issue, just had no fix. Thank you